# Folder sync application which can sync over Internet (the other machine specified by an IP)?

Tags: windows, internet, sync

I need to sync some folders between two Win 7 machines. While they are connected to the same LAN, they can't see each-other over Windows Networking since sharing is disabled on both of them (security reasons).

Do you know any sync app which can work over IP?

The folder I need to sync has 500,000 files in it (80 GB in total), so the sync app should be pretty efficient. At the moment I copy the files from one machine to the other over FTP, but it takes forever, since a separate connection is opened for each file.

Or maybe you know some app which can efficiently transfer a large number of files between two machines on the Internet?

Comment: Why do you have sharing disabled? are you not on a home network?

Answer (score 2):

I did use [PowerFolder](http://www.powerfolder.com) back when the free version didn't have any limitations but now you have to pay $60 to manage more than 1GB of storage.

I had a bit of a look around and found [CrashPlan](http://b4.crashplan.com/consumer/index.html) which allows you to synchronise files between your own computers and storage devices for free. It also uses compression and deltas to minimise data transfer so, if you synchronise the 2 computers first, it should be quick and painless after that. I think it even does file versioning, if that is something you're after.

I'm glad you asked the question - it gave me an excuse to take another look at these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use DropBox for this. You can get a 100GB account for $200/year

[dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/) that i believe can do both network and IP synchronization.

Comment: I tried it, since the site said that it supports sync over network. But it doesn't

Comment: well to be honest in order to backup/sync that ammount of data will take a lot of time and bandwidth since if it's conducted over IP i believe it will be conducted over the internet thus leaving the speed but here's a [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/372175/free-ways-to-synchronize-folders-between-computers) link that might help more.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Windows Live Mesh is perfect for this.  But I think they are discontinuing the folder syncing aspect of the service in January, unless I am misunderstanding the email they sent out this week.

Answer (score 0):

(I just posted this in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/505256/synchronize-folders-on-different-computers-without-cloud-and-without-network-jus), but I think it applies equally well here.)

[BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) is a relatively new player in the synchronization arena. While it's in beta, it's in constant development, always improving, and always **free** (unlike Cubby). It's designed to be secure and not to use external servers (only a direct connection between PCs). It can use trackers and relays if it's unable to establish a direct connection to another PC, but that's optional and can be disabled. It's worth looking at because, unlike Cubby, it lets you establish a read-only connection for a folder, so that the target machine cannot modify the source machine's files. This is a *very* nice feature for backup/archive machines.

As for using an IP address, BTSync uses a "secret" rather than machine names or IP addresses, so it should fulfill your needs.

(As of version 1.1.48)