# Synchronize folders on different computers without cloud and without network just internet

Tags: windows, sync

I have two computers with windows 7, one in my home town and one in another town. They are not in private network but I have internet on both. They have exactly the same file structure. I am searching for program that can keep the data equal.

I know about dropbox or google drive but they are cloud and I don't want to use them. Also they are using folder that you should copy your data in it. There is another programs that are like a server, just put something and after that you can download it but I don't need them.

I want just to point which folders to be synchronized and the program make the synchronization. The sync can be in real time if the two computers are powered, or after some time when they are powered. Or it can lock another computer synced folder till update is required. At all this is my documents that I want to be synced in all my computers and to be changed from where I want. In fact I can move the updates with flash but if some program save the changes and make them on another computer with one click it will facilitate my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cubby will do exactly what you want: Sync folders between systems on the internet. It has cloud options as well, but they can be ignored if you'd like. It creates a "My Cubby" folder, but you don't have to use it. Any folder can be a cubby. The peer to peer sync is its major feature over its competitors.

Answer (score 1):

[Cubby](http://cubby.com) is a perfect solution for the OP, but it won't work for a slightly different situation--namely, syncing between *different* Cubby accounts (i.e., shared folders).

While Cubby **will** sync between different computers using the *same* Cubby account without requiring the files to be uploaded to The Cloud, it **cannot** sync between different computers using *different* Cubby accounts. That means if I share a folder with a family member, it **must** be synced to Cubby's cloud. This is an unfortunate disadvantage over the soon-to-be-defunct MS Live Mesh system.

(As of version 1.0.0.10898)

[BitTorrent Sync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) is a relatively new player in the synchronization arena. While it's in beta, it's in constant development, always improving, and always **free** (unlike Cubby). It's designed to be secure and not to use external servers (only a direct connection between PCs). It can use trackers and relays if it's unable to establish a direct connection to another PC, but that's optional and can be disabled. It's worth looking at because, unlike Cubby, it lets you establish a read-only connection for a folder, so that the target machine cannot modify the source machine's files. This is a *very* nice feature for backup/archive machines.

(As of version 1.1.48)

Comment: You will be able make comments as soon as you hit 50 reputation.

Comment: If you link your account here to your other stackexchange sites you get 100 points for free!!!

Answer (score 0):

As for **Nov 2014**, I would go for [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com/). I think it is mature enough to be used without problems and its free.

There's a new program called [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) that looks quite promising. It's similar to BitTorrent Sync but it's Open Source and used and Open Protocol. The only problem is that they still didn't released the version 1.0, so it may still be a little bit "buggy".